# Max of pandas grouped data frame returns blank assertion error

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the below error when trying to find the max of a grouped data frame. I have dozens of columns in this data frame and I know one, or more, are causing this problem. But I do not know which one. Please save me from brute force trying to figure out this problem.

What data type would cause this problem? What causes the assertion error to be blank?

Original Code:

```
preclin.groupby(['StudyLocation', 'StudyID',
                               'ProductLotNo', 'ProductLotNoDetails',
                               'Dose_CARCellperBody', 'Dose_CellperBody', 'SubjectID'],
                              as_index=False).min()['Time_Days']
```

Error Message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-c45e8b9b8ce4> in <module>
      2                                'ProductLotNo', 'ProductLotNoDetails',
      3                                'Dose_CARCellperBody', 'Dose_CellperBody', 'SubjectID'],
----> 4                               as_index=False).min()['Time_Days']
      5 # preclin[['StudyLocation', 'StudyID', 'ProductLotNo', 'ProductLotNoDetails', 'Time_Days']].groupby(
      6 #     ['StudyLocation', 'StudyID', 'ProductLotNo', 'ProductLotNoDetails']).max().describe()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in f(self, **kwargs)
   1369                 # try a cython aggregation if we can
   1370                 try:
-> 1371                     return self._cython_agg_general(alias, alt=npfunc, **kwargs)
   1372                 except DataError:
   1373                     pass

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
    992     ) -> DataFrame:
    993         agg_blocks, agg_items = self._cython_agg_blocks(
--> 994             how, alt=alt, numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count
    995         )
    996         return self._wrap_agged_blocks(agg_blocks, items=agg_items)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1098             # Clean up the mess left over from split blocks.
   1099             for locs, result in zip(split_items, split_frames):
-> 1100                 assert len(locs) == result.shape[1]
   1101                 for i, loc in enumerate(locs):
   1102                     new_items.append(np.array([loc], dtype=locs.dtype))

AssertionError:
```

[image]

Comment: And what's the error? Also please paste the code/error as text.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the original code and error.

Comment: Try: `preclin.groupby(['StudyLocation', 'StudyID',
                               'ProductLotNo', 'ProductLotNoDetails',
                               'Dose_CARCellperBody', 'Dose_CellperBody', 'SubjectID'])['Time_Days'].min()`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely getting this error because you have NaN values in your `DataFrame`.

`max()` and `min()` both seem to throw a blank assertion error if you try and aggregate where there are null values. Try and remove them or filter them out first?